# Wrong Environment in Trac SVN post-commit-hook

Tags: python, trac, system-administration

I use a the SVN post-commit-hook script from the official Trac website to update tickets the tickets. ([This is the script](http://trac-hacks.org/browser/timingandestimationplugin/branches/trac0.11/scripts/trac-post-commit.py)) If a user commits something into SVN, the ticket gets the update and an E-Mail is generated. This works fine with one exception:

It seems the environment in the post-commit-hook is different from the website. If I change something in a ticket, the email looks like this:

```
[bla bla]
--
Ticket URL: <https://host/trac/projectname/ticket/100#comment:2>
projectname <https://host/trac/projectname>
My example project
```

If I change the ticket from the post-commit-hook, the amil looks like this:

```
[bla bla]
--
Ticket URL: </ticket/100#comment:2>
projectname <>
My example project
```

I manage several trac instances on this server with a global configuration in `/etc/trac/trac.ini` and a local configuration on the project folders. It seems like the post-commit-hook gets a wrong environment without set the right **project url**. How can I set this right?

Comment: By 'project url' you mean setting base_url in [trac] section of trac.ini per environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.11, you need to set `base_url` under `[trac]` to the same value as `url` under `[project]`. [Ticket #3965](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/3965) has some more information.